# Determine whether there is a winner in tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

Below a function which answers: is there a winner in tic-tac-toe game?

Also, there is a test suite I wrote for it.

````
def is_win(field):
    # check horizontal
    N = len(field)
    for i in range(N):
        if field[i][0] != 0 and len(set(field[i])) == 1:
            return True
        vertical = [field[j][i] for j in range(N)]
        if vertical[0] != 0 and len(set(vertical)) == 1:
            return True
    # check diagonal
    diagonal = [field[i][i] for i in range(N)]
    if diagonal[0] != 0 and len(set(diagonal)) == 1:
        return True
    o_diagonal = [field[N-i-1][i] for i in range(N)]
    if o_diagonal[0] != 0 and len(set(o_diagonal)) == 1:
        return True
    return False

assert is_win(
        [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [0, 0, 0],
            ]) == True

print(1)
assert is_win(
        [
            [0, 2, 0],
            [0, 2, 0],
            [0, 2, 0],
            ]) == True
print(2)
assert is_win(
        [
            [0, 0, 2],
            [2, 2, 1],
            [0, 0, 1],
            ]) == False
print(3)

assert is_win(
        [
            [2, 0, 0],
            [0, 2, 0],
            [0, 0, 2],
            ]) == True
print(4)
assert is_win(
        [
            [0, 0, 2],
            [0, 2, 0],
            [2, 0, 0],
            ]) == True
print(5)
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your code is WET.

  > ```
  > var[0] != 0 and len(set(var)) == 1
  > ```

  Is repeated four times.
- `field[len(field)-i-1]` can be simplified to `field[~i]`.
- I'd personally just use a couple of `any` and a couple of `or`s.

```
def is_unique_player(values):
    return values[0] != 0 and len(set(values)) == 1


def is_win(field):
    N = len(field)
    return (
        any(is_unique_player(row) for row in field)
        or any(is_unique_player(column) for column in zip(*field))
        or is_unique_player([field[i][i] for i in range(N)])
        or is_unique_player([field[~i][i] for i in range(N)])
    )
```